# How to change color of select field with empty value?

Tags: html, jquery, css, django, forms

I created an app with Django as its backend and I have a form that features a dropdown with Foreign Key elements. The problem is that I want the dropdown option that doesn't have a value (i.e. the first empty/placeholder option) to be a different colour when unfocused than the options that do have  values. I am using Bootstrap 4 and right now the `form-control` class is setting all the form inputs to a specific color, even the dropdown's colour? How can I change this with CSS, JQuery or both?

Comment: create an snippet please.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini of what!?

Comment: post your code or how we can help you?